# How can I share data between Rails app and client (always available)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, initialization, asset-pipeline

I'd like to be able to define a ruby method that returns a Hash of data, but I'd also like it to be part of the application.js file on app initialization.

**actual data**: everything is defined here (in lib or config, I guess?)

```
def shared_data
  { foo: bar }
end
```

**in app** (how do i access shared_data in app?)

```
def some_method 
  shared_data # => { :foo => 'bar' }
end
```

**generated js file on app initialization** (how do i generate and include in application.js)

```
var shared_data = { "foo": "bar" };
```

My questions:

1. Where should I place this `shared_data` method?
2. How can I generate and include this JavaScript?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If this data does not change after app initialization

You can put this in `config/initializer/shared_data.rb` and assign it to a Constant or $global variable, this way this data will be available application wide

`$shared_data = { x:1, y:2 }`

Then create a javascript file `assets/javascripts/main.js.erb`**(note the .erb ext)**, include this in `application.js` and you will be able to access this data

`var sharedData = <%= $shared_data %>`

**Caution:**
This data will get compiled and become static with `assets:precompile` in prodution